# how to style checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am styling check-box in HTML using Jquery, but its not appearing in the browser . when i  checked the browser element property it is showing the style has applied to the element but its not showing in the browser . 
This is my **Jquery** code

```
$("form :checkbox:checked").css("border", "3px solid green");
```

I am using jquery version 2.2.2, I have checked 1.9.1,1.10,1.12 all are failing and I am using Firefox version 45 and chrome version 49.x .
here is the Jsfiddle version of this code [source code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o93f3za6/3/)

Comment: Do you need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/o93f3za6/4/ or this https://jsfiddle.net/o93f3za6/5/ ??

Comment: You cannot customize default checkbox. To do, [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: i appreciate you answer and i know its works that way , is it my code version is old or deprecated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using outline instead of border, like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $('form input:checkbox:checked').css("outline", "3px solid red");
})
```

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/36ccvk4h/7/

Comment: thanks man that worked. border is the problem  and its worked with outline.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "form input:checkbox:checked" )
  .wrap( "<span></span>" )
  .parent()
  .css({
    border: "3px red solid"
  });
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/PrabuB/999zzxm6/3/)